# VBA save path dilemma

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Const SAVE_PATH = "S:\Divisional Support\RVU Programs\Payroll 2015\2015-01 January\Provider Performance PDF's"

   Dim cell As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim counter As Long

   Set wsSummary = Sheets("PERFORMANCE ANALYSIS")

   For Each cell In Worksheets("MEMORIAL HOSPITAL OF YORK").Range("$A$200:$A$226")
      If cell.Value <> "" Then

         'progress in status bar
         counter = counter + 1
         Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

         With wsSummary
            .Range("$A$6").Value = cell.Value
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                  Filename:=cell.Value & ".pdf", _
                  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                  OpenAfterPublish:=False
         End With
      End If
  Next cell

   Set wsSummary = Nothing
End Sub
```

For some reason I can't explain it not saving in location : S:\Divisional Support\RVU Programs\Payroll 2015\2015-01 January\Provider Performance PDF's

Instead it's saving : S:\Divisional Support\RVU Programs\Payroll 2015\MOCK Folder for Ryan

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see where you use SAVE_PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `SAVE_PATH` variable in export part. Try:

```
Filename:= SAVE_PATH & "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf"
```

Comment: user3964075 I get a run-time error now. I use to have Save Path included but it put the save path, in the file's name.

Comment: I want to create a pdf for each selection in my drop down, so the cell value is there to make it dynamic for each selection in my drop down.

Comment: @user3666237 but what do those cells exactly contain? does it include full path (as in SAVE_PATH)? if not - where exactly do you "put the save path, in the file's name"? there are no signs of it in your code

Comment: With wsSummary
            .Range("$A$6").Value = cell.Value
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                  Filename:=SAVE_PATH & cell.Value & ".pdf", _
                  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                  IgnorePrintAreas:=False  OpenAfterPublish:=False                                                                                                  This was the original code  I removed the file name because it will save the file with "Provider Performance PDF's, in front of the cell value

Comment: @user3666237 - because your code did not include `& "\" &` - as in my answer. Please replace your line with my answer and it should work OK

Comment: @user3666237 or you can just add \ at the and of your constant

Comment: I get Run-Time error '1004'
Document not save.  The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving.

Comment: @user3666237 OK, it looks like there are only 2 options left. If it worked without backslash (but Provider Performance PDF's was concatenated), and doesn't work with backslash, it means that: the path is wrong (Provider Performance PDF's does not exist), or it exists and you don't have write permissions for it.

Comment: @user3666237 you can easily test both: start PDF export manually. Do not navigate to destination folder. Instead - copy full SAVE_PATH variable value (without double quotes). Paste it in the address bar and press enter. Enter file name and try to save it.

Comment: Thanks so much that was it my file destination.